# Trouble accessing Json from Web API call in ADF and inserting in SQL table

Tags: sql, json, rest, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a REST API that I use to extract the data.
I am using Azure data factory to do that by using web component and then taking that Json output and using Stored Procedure and trying to insert into database table.

When i do the test in SQL with sample Json it works fine, where as json that's coming from WEB call in ADF has the "" in front of each node value like below.

```
[{\"company_id\":\"test\",\"condition_assessments_ID\":\"SON-testMOTION-SON-MOTION ANALYSIS - SMA & test-2022-04-27@10_00_00\"}]
```

And i think because of that i was getting error like

> "Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0."

This is one issue and to avoid it so i was converting the Json as string and which is putting more back slashes and its not helping.

How to preserve the json formatting so its straight forward for a stored proc to insert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape character backslash `\` appears wherever double quotes are present in the Azure data factory.

Even though the Stored procedure input is shown with a backslash, when data is loaded to Sink (SQL Table) it removes backslashes and data is inserted in JSON format.

I have repro’d in my lab with sample API data and was able to load as expected.

1. Web activity output:

[image]

2. Pass output of web activity to stored procedure parameter by converting it to string. Here I am only passing the data part from the output.

`@string(activity('Web1').output.data)`

[image]

Stored procedure Input:

[image]

SQL table data after the stored procedure is run:

[image]